# How to remove double quote between double quotes

Tags: shell, powershell, unix

How to remove double quote that is between a set of double quotes?

`"Test T"est"` should get output as `"Test Test"`

`"Test T"est", "Test1 "Test1"` should get output as `"Test Test", "Test1 Test1"`

Comment: A machine cannot possibly filter out unescaped double quotes, especially in the second example. How it is supposed to know, which double quote to remove? But if there is a pattern (like maximum double quotes that should not be there per string: 1) you could write a script to remove the second, and then every third double quote.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `awk`:

```
$ awk -F", *" '{                           # Set the field separator
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){                      # Loop through all fields
     $i="\""gensub("\"", "", "g", $i)"\""  # Rebuild the field with only surrounding quotes
  }
}1' OFS="," file                           # Print the line 
"Test Test","Test1 Test1"
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is a corrupted CSV and you can say there are no commas inside the fields, then PowerShell's CSV handling will read them and leave the trailing quote. Remove that, then re-export to a new CSV to get values with double quotes around them.

```
import-csv .\test.csv -Header 'column1', 'column2' | 
    ForEach-Object {

        foreach ($column in $_.psobject.properties.Name)
        {
          $_.$column = $_.$column.Replace('"', '') 
        }

        $_ 

     } | Export-Csv .\test2.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

If the file has headers in it, remove the `-header 'column1', 'column2'` part.

Comment: We are getting .dat with which had data with , seperator

Comment: In the data we have " between " " and it is givinf error while processing, so we need to remove " between " " and then process the .dat file

Answer (score 1):

So if this is for a corrupted CSV you could state the problem as remove any double quotes that don't appear at the start or end of a line and that are not near a comma (with optional white space). So this can easily be done with a Powershell regex like so:

```
$t = '"Test T"est", "Test1 "Test1"'
$t -replace '(?<!^|\s*,\s*)"(?!\s*,\s*|$)', ''
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative with sed:

```
sed 's/\("[^"]\+\)"\([^"]\+"\)/\1\2/g' inputFile
```

input:

```
"Test T"est"
"Test T"est", "Test1 "Test1"
```

output:

```
"Test Test"
"Test Test", "Test1 Test1"
```

Comment: This should work in GNU's sed, for BSD's sed try using option `-E` or `-r`, for example `sed -E 's/.../.../g' inputFile`